# AngularJS. Best practice structuring blog posts in JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

Now I have 2 JSON files responsible for articles content. One is used to keep all articles for posting on the home page. articles.json

```
[
{
    "id":"1",
    "category": "books",
    "title": "Article title here",
    "short_desc": "Short desc here, maybe a bit longer",
    "images": [
        "img/article-img1.jpg"
    ] ,
    "featured_stat":true,
    "featured_img": [
        "img/featured-img-1.jpg"
    ]
}
]
```

Then I use following construction for getting articles details for particular article based on URL:

```
app.controller('ArticleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('pages/articles/' + $routeParams.articleId + '.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.article = data;
        });

}]);
```

1.json article file look like this

```
 {
"id":"1",
"category": "Books & Magazines",
"title": "Title here",
"html_desc": "<p>Article content here</p>",
"images": [
    "img/featured-img-1.jpg"
]
```

}

So if URL is /article/1 it looks for 1.json file from the articles folder. Now I think maybe it's better to combine these json files into one and keep all articles info in one place. Is this a good idea and how to check what article to load based on URL in this code, how to structure this bigger JSON? I will have about 30 articles.

And one side question, is there a way to edit or add new articles to this JSON?

Comment: can't edit static files without using a server language to do it. Do you not have any server side storage? If not look into one of the many free cloud storage services that provide javascript API's

Comment: Can you share a link where I can learn more about server side JS APIs

Comment: one example, there are many, is https://mongolab.com/